# Not letting me build my android project, but lets me debug it in Unity 2019.1.6f1 Personal

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, building

This is my first project that I am actually building for android, and am unfortunately feeling quite unmotivated due to the fact that I've been trying to fix this issue for over a month (possibly two at this point, I'm not sure).  The code is working just fine when I debug and run it, and it also builds perfectly fine for Windows.  The issue comes when I try to build it for Android.  I've tried numerous different things but I am at a complete lost of ideas at this point and would appreciate any help possible.

Thank you very much in advance!

Ryan

**Last error I got in console after attempting to build it:**

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 48 errors   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

**Photos and Videos**

[Click to see photo of error on-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXIHb.png)
In this photo, the highlighted circle indicates the error I got on screen, and the small red circle shows where I've tried every possible option in that drop down menu.  None of them worked.  There are other player settings ad build settings that I have attempted to change but no luck :(

Additionally, I have uploaded a video to TechSmith ScreenCast to show all the errors I have received in the console.  All the warning and errors were not present before the first time building it, and now (after building it numerous times) they are always there, even after reverting to a previous save.  I have no clue what is going on but if you think you could help I would be very happy.  Here it is: https://www.screencast.com/t/HIYWP8RMyNh

Thanks :)  Very much looking forward to getting this resolved!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages. Paste the error messages in your question so we can just read them right away.